# Matching Individuals to a single group

Tags: r

I have to match students to their teachers using students' id and their teachers' id. One student can be paired with only one teacher. However, a student may have multiple entries with the same teacher. I want to retain only the cases where students are matched to a single unique teacher. Here is an example to the data frame.
    `CHID <- c(111,111,111,112,112,113,113,113,113,114), TEAID <- c(115,115,115,162,165,168,168,168,187,119), SCORE <- c(56,56,56,55,55,58,58,58,58,64)`

From these data, I want to retain students with CHID's 111 and 114 since they are matched to one and only one unique teacher. Can some please help with an r-code for performing this task? Your assistance will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution using `dplyr` package -

```
df <- data.frame(
CHID = c(111,111,111,112,112,113,113,113,113,114),
TEAID = c(115,115,115,162,165,168,168,168,187,119),
SCORE = c(56,56,56,55,55,58,58,58,58,64)
)

group_by(df, CHID) %>% filter(n_distinct(TEAID) == 1) %>% ungroup()

# A tibble: 4 x 3
#    CHID TEAID SCORE
#   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1   111   115  56.0
# 2   111   115  56.0
# 3   111   115  56.0
# 4   114   119  64.0
```

Here's a solution without any foreign packages -

```
df[ave(df$TEAID, df$CHID, FUN = function(x) length(unique(x))) == 1, ]

#    CHID TEAID SCORE
# 1   111   115    56
# 2   111   115    56
# 3   111   115    56
# 10  114   119    64
```

Comment: Thank you both. Appreciate your assistance. However, I have a question. I forgot to mention that teachers can have students. Will I have to make adjustments to these codes?